# Has Kartikeya kill any other demons other than Tarakasura?

Tags: kartikeya

As per the story of Kartikeya, the god destroyed the demon Tarakasura.Some stories claim that he even killed the demon's brothers,Surapadman and another demon,whose name I have forgotten.However,other than this story,I have not come across any other tales of Kartikeya vanquishing demons.Has Kartikeya kill any other demons too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **गांगेयस्ताम्रचूडश्च ब्रह्मचारी शिखिध्वजः ।**
>   **तारकारिरुमापुत्रः क्रौंचारिश्च षडाननः ॥२॥**
>
> Gaangeyas-Taamra-Cuuddashca Brahmacaarii Shikhi-Dhvajah |
>   Taaraka-Arir-Umaa-Putrah Krauncaa-Rishca Ssaddaananah ||2||
>
> Meaning:
>   2.1: (Salutations to Sri Kartikeya) Who is Loved by Mother Ganga and His FollowerTamrachuda, Who is Celebate and has Peacock as His Emblem,
>   2.2: Who is the Enemy of Tarakasura and Krauncasura, Who is the Son of Devi Uma and has Six Faces.

[Kartikeya Pragya Vivardhana Stotram](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_murugan-kartikeya_pragya_vivardhana_stotram.php)

**Kartikeya is a Hindu deity also known as Skanda and Murugan and Subhramanya.(कार्तिकेय , स्कन्द , मुरुगन , सुब्रह्मण्य)**

We find mentioning of Skanda Or Kartikeya  in Salya Parva  Of **Great Epic Mahabharata.(शल्य पर्व. महाभारत)  book 9 Chapter 46 ,** and his stories about fighting and killing of many daityas.

**These are excerpts -:**

> Thousands of daityas, O king, were burnt with the flames that issued
>   from Skanda's dart, while others breathed their last, terrified by the
>   roars of Skanda.

> The adorable Skanda, inflamed with rage, quickly slew the son
>   of **daitya chief (Bali)** along with his younger brother.
>
> **He then, in that battle, slew Mahisha** who was surrounded by eight padmas of daityas. He **next slew Tripada** who was surrounded
>   by a 1,000 ajutas of daityas. The puissant Skanda then slew Hradodara,
>   who was surrounded by tennikharvas of daityas,  Then Bali's son Vana
>   of great might, getting upon the **Kraunca** mountain, battled with
>   the celestial host. Possessed of great intelligence, the great
>   generalissimo Skanda rushed against that foe of the gods. From fear of
>   Kartikeya, he took shelter within the Kraunca mountain. Inflamed with
>   rage, the adorable Kartikeya then pierced that mountain with that dart
>   given him by Agni. The mountain was called Kraunca (crane) because of
>   the sound it always produced resembled the cry of a crane. That
>   mountain was variegated with shala trees. The apes and elephants on it
>   were affrighted. The birds that had their abode on it rose up and
>   wheeled around in the welkin. The snakes began to dart down its sides.
>   It resounded also with the cries of leopards and bears in large
>   numbers that ran hither and thither in fear. Other forests on it rang
>   with the cries of hundreds upon hundreds of animals.Sharabhas and
>   lions suddenly ran out. In consequence of all this that mountain,
>   though it was reduced to a very pitiable plight, still assumed a very
>   beautiful aspect. The vidyadharas dwelling on its summits soared into
>   the air. The kinnaras also became very anxious, distracted by the fear
>   caused by the fall of Skanda's dart. The daityas then, by hundreds and
>   thousands, came out of that blazing mountain, all clad in beautiful
>   ornaments and garlands.

[Mahabharata Shalya Parva Book 9 chapter 46](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09046.htm)

Comment: @SwiftPuskar I thought Mahisha was killed by Durga

Comment: @KVickneshvara - There are two Recensions of stories of Skanda or Kartikeya ( Northern and Southern Recensions ) so , I have given the Ref. From Sacred Text web site to avoide confusion. There may be different believes according to regions also. See this - http://murugan.org/research/kannan2009.htm

Comment: @KVickneshvara - Pls. also see the another Ref.for Mahisha - http://community.fortunecity.ws/millenium/castleton/273/sc_en.html#start

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is an evidence/story in [Skanda Purana](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/SkandaPurana.html) about Kartikeya killing **many demons** along with a prominent  demon called **Pralamb**.

Below is how Skanda purana describe the incidence:

> A demon named Pralamb had escaped unharmed in the battle fought
>   between the deities and demons. As the deities were busy installing
>   Shivalingas at different places, Pralamb started to torment their
>   families in their absence. The deities got this information from Kumud
>   who appeared at the time when the deities were digging up a reservoir
>   near 'Siddheshwar' temple.All the deities requested Kartikeya to do
>   something. Kartikeya released his fiery weapon, Shakti in the
>   direction of Pralamb. Shakti pierced the heart of earth and went right
>   up to Patal loka where Pralamb lived with the surviving demons. All
>   the demons were killed within few moments.

So, yes, Kartikeya may be more known for killing Tarakasur, he also killed several other demons too, as per Skanda Purana.

Comment: "Shakti pierced the heart of earth and went right up to Patal loka" Patala Loka is not inside earth.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria hmm.. I see. But to be honest, I just used the ref. as Is. not sure if translation/interpretations is correct.